# How do you refresh the data in a mongoose document that has already been loaded?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

To be clear this question relates to loading data from the database, not updating documents in the database.

With the following schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema
  name: String
  code:
    type: String
    index:
      unique: true
  _contacts: [
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: 'Person'
  ]
```

I've created my document like so:

```
client = new Client code:'test',name:'test competition',contacts:[]
client.save()
```

Elsewhere in the application or via an API call, somewhere that it can't easily refer to the version cached above:

```
Client.findOne(code:'test').exec (err,client) ->
  return if err or not client
  client._contacts.push person.id # person has come from somewhere
  client.save (err) ->
    return err if err
```

If we return to our original *client* object what I would like to know is if there's a way to refresh that object either for the whole document or just a particular path. For instance;

```
client.refresh '_contacts', (err) ->
  return err if err
```

Or would it be better practice to maintain only one object that is referred to globally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best practice is to only keep a Mongoose model instance like `client` around as long as you're actively using it, precisely because it can so easily become out of sync with what's in the database.  Recreate your `client` object whenever you need it using `findOne` instead of trying to refresh potentially stale copies.